# Background Attr Not Working in Android View

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-view

I am trying to get default ripple effect but i am unable to figure out why its not working for me. here is my code.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.enam.rippledemo.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Android Version : LOLLIPOP**

where i am making mistake?

Comment: make the textview clickable / focusable and try may be?

Comment: @SandipSoni yap it worked. but will it support on pre-lollipop?

Comment: It won't give the ripple effect on pre-lollipop, but it'll give a kind of "pressed" look to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this make your `TextView` **`android:clickable="true"`**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"

The error you see is pointing out that ?android:attr/selectableItemBackground is available for API versions >= 11. True, indeed.